# How natural is this practice of omitting the subject in speech?

Tags: subject-pronoun-drop

A [movie clip](https://youtu.be/D9bqc8LZ3UA?t=5s) of the movie 'Justice League' starts with this monologue by Bruce Wayne:

> I believe there is a stranger **(1)** comes to this village from the sea **(2)** comes in the winter when the people are hungry **(3)** brings fish. He comes on the king tide. That was last night.

First, please listen to the clip to see if you can hear any sound in (1), (2) and/or (3). If not, please answer the questions below.

There's a pause in (1), (2) and (3). Is "He" omitted from all of these?

> I believe there is a stranger. **He** comes to this village from the sea. **He** comes in the winter when the people are hungry. **He** brings fish. He comes on the king tide. That was last night.

Or is "who" omitted from (1) and "he" from (2) and (3)?

> I believe there is a stranger **who** comes to this village from the sea. **He** comes in the winter when the people are hungry. **He** brings fish. He comes on the king tide. That was last night.

In any case, how natural is this practice of omitting the subject of a clause -- be it "he" or "who" -- in speech?

Comment: I'll write a comment instead of an answer because I am not quite sure what the answer is but I don't think it's a very common way to speak. I don't hear "he" or "who" omitted very often or maybe my brain just fills it in automatically. I think the guy playing Batman might have been speaking that way to emphasize the solemnity of the situation and give a special sort of *effect* to his speech in that moment.

Comment: Listen again. I hear "who" and "he" at (2) is both unnecessary and preserves hiding the gender until he says: "He brings fish".

Comment: I'm with Rob - it almost sounds like the words are indeed there, just hardly voiced. Especially with the force that the C in "come" is pronounced both times - it sounds like it's coming off a vowel.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Can you hear (1)? If so, is it _who_ or _He_?

Comment: It sounds like "who" to me. I don't hear the "wh", but when he says "comes", it sounds like it's coming off an "oo" sound.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe there is a **stranger**. Comes to this village from the sea. Comes in the winter when the people are hungry. Brings fish. **He** comes on the king tide.

The omission of the pronoun is natural in speech when the subject is understood. And this omission is used in the scene  to create an air of mystery and tension as user @Rob suggested in their answer.

There's no need to punctuate every statement with the pronoun, the subject is clearly nominated from the start.

The term "a stranger" is used, and moviegoers see a beefed up ‘man’ with long brown hair and piercing ice-blue eyes, standing alone on  Bruce Wayne's left. Aquaman is present in the scene, so Wayne's speech is clearly referring to him.

UPDATE

I found a different trailer on YouTube, entitled *[Justice League Official Comic-Con Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=6&v=fIHH5-HVS9o)* (2017) - *Ben Affleck Movie*, it has something like 42 million views, and I can distinctly hear the pronoun "who" uttered by Bruce Wayne's deep smokey voice. The entire mini-dialogue is the following

> **Bruce Wayne**: There is a... stranger **who** comes to this village from the sea. Comes in the winter when the people are hungry, and [*the conjunction is barely audible*] brings fish.  Comes on the king tide. That was last night.
>   **Arthur Curry** (*alias* Aqua Man): Talk

So, as can be seen, *and* heard, the relative pronoun **who** is used, and I also detect a mumbled "and" which joins the two clauses: Comes in the winter[…] **and** brings fish.

The pronoun *he* might be uttered before "comes". Unfortunately, my hearing is far from perfect, so I might be mistaken here. In any case, it isn't essential because the person being described is the "stranger" **who** brings fish to the village in winter.

Comment: From your punctuation, I guess you think (1) is _He_, not _who_. If I'm guessing correctly, what makes you think it's _He_, not _who_?

Comment: @jk2 either fits, if you're going the two clauses together then It makes sense to use "who" but in the movie they don't. It's best that you ask the screenwriter or Ben Affleck, why "who" or "he" was omitted.

Comment: If indeed _comes to this village from the sea_ is a subordinate clause that modifies _stranger_, shouldn't _who_ be mandatory? Because _who_ acts as a subject in the relative clause and thus cannot be omitted, I think.

Comment: @JK2 **IF**..are you 100% sure that it is a subordinate clause? Can you prove it? Does it really matter? Neither "who" nor "he" is uttered anyway. Besides, your question specifically asks about omitting the subject (pronoun) from statements. The subject is clearly understood, you can leave out pronouns in informal speech and writing.

Comment: It's not that I'm 100% sure that it's a subordinate clause, but that semantically it's probable that it is. That's why I said "If indeed..." More importantly, you yourself said, "either fits". So I was asking, if _who_ could be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIHH5-HVS9o). Download the SubTitles.

```
<body>
<SYNC Start=1220><P class='en'>There is a stranger
<SYNC Start=3100><P class='en'>&nbsp;
<SYNC Start=4000><P class='en'>who comes to this village from the sea.
<SYNC Start=5600><P class='en'>&nbsp;
<SYNC Start=7000><P class='en'>He comes in the winter, when people are hungry
<SYNC Start=8900><P class='en'>&nbsp;
<SYNC Start=8900><P class='en'>brings fish
<SYNC Start=9800><P class='en'>&nbsp;
<SYNC Start=10140><P class='en'>comes on the King tide.
<SYNC Start=11700><P class='en'>&nbsp;
<SYNC Start=12880><P class='en'>That was last night.
<SYNC Start=13720><P class='en'>&nbsp;
<SYNC Start=20400><P class='en'>Talk.
<SYNC Start=20900><P class='en'>&nbsp;
<SYNC Start=23080><P class='en'>I believe that an enemy is coming
<SYNC Start=24560><P class='en'>&nbsp;
<SYNC Start=25480><P class='en'>from far away.
<SYNC Start=26380><P class='en'>&nbsp;
<SYNC Start=28100><P class='en'>I&#39;m looking for warriors,
<SYNC Start=29220><P class='en'>&nbsp;
<SYNC Start=30380><P class='en'>a stranger,
<SYNC Start=31280><P class='en'>&nbsp;
<SYNC Start=33660><P class='en'>others like him.
<SYNC Start=34680><P class='en'>&nbsp;
<SYNC Start=36980><P class='en'>I&#39;m building an alliance to defend us .
```

> There is a stranger   who comes to this village from the sea.   He comes in the winter, when people are hungry   brings fish   comes on the King tide.   That was last night.   Talk.   I believe that an enemy is coming   from far away.   I'm looking for warriors,   a stranger,   others like him.   I'm building an alliance to defend us .

He is speaking, the people are listening; think about ***why*** they listen, they could tell him to shut it or walk up and poke him in the eye (what's he gonna do about it).

He doesn't [mince words](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mince+words), you know to listen or not. That's what that scene portrays.

Comment: I wouldn't consider showing another version to be an answer to my question. Moreover, movie trailers tend to have edited lines than actual movie clips have, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: I didn't watch the trailer clip you posted, it's the same clip I watched and whose link I posted the other day, you can definitely hear "who" being said. Here's +1 for finding the original trailer before anyone.

Comment: Thanks @Mari-Lou. The reason I used that clip is because it is no different except it has SubTitles which you can read. It is as I mentioned in my comment to the question, the words are there and it is spoken in that manner to get everyone to buy-in. He wants to garner trust and inspire loyalty en masse. What is being said isn't a joke or to be taken lightly, it's their problem. It's direct, abrupt, curt or short (definition 6): https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/short

Comment: @Mari-LouA Maybe you're not familiar with the whole process of making trailers and clips. Most of the time, and I believe it's the case here as well, movie "clips" as shown in the OP are made from the original movie, whereas move "trailers", original or not, tend to have a different wording from that of the original movie. So I'm sure that the original movie doesn't have "who", which for some reason may have been inserted in the trailer as an afterthought.

Comment: @JK2 no, that trailer was made in 2016, almost a full year before the actual movie was released. The "who" is definitely heard, off-camera maybe, but it's definitely audible.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What I mean is the wording of the actual movie is not the same as the "original" trailer but the same as the clip.

Comment: @JK2 this is probably a question better suited to SE Movies & TV, or SE Filmaking if such a site existed. It seems that in the final version the word "who" was a victim of the editing process.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think so. Do you seriously think that the people who edited the final version "accidentally" removed "who"? In a big budget movie like this one, it's not even a possibility.

Comment: @JK2 why not? Money doesn't guarantee quality or craftmanship. Have you never seen bloopers? There are far more serious errors that have passed through the net than a pronoun that got cut out. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Maybe this question was better suited to English Language and Usage. Regarding removing 'who', I've seen native speakers drop 'who' or 'that' in "There is...." or "It is..." constructions.

Comment: @JK2 so you agree that omitting the subject or relative pronoun is nothing new. Great! Thumbs up.

Answer (score -2):

In English, omitting the Subject or personal pronouns is not accepted unlike in European languages like 'Italian', where it is more common to start a sentence with the actual action(verb).

Update: For everyone's benefit, I would elaborate on the answer. Some languages are null-subject languages and some are not.

Please refer:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-subject_language

Comment: *Not accepted* in English? Sure about that? English is *also* a European language.

Comment: ^ English is incredibly European, Brexit isn't changing that.

Comment: And, the practice of omitting subjects actually is occasionally acceptable, especially in informal speech.

Comment: @Mari-LouA and Joel - Hope this clarifies better. Have a great day

Comment: Hello, the link seems to suggest that Italian, Russian and Polish are some of the European languages that have this type of syntax. The other languages mentioned are non-European. But, in English, I assure you that the pronoun can be safely omitted in those cases where the subject has been mentioned previously or is clearly understood from context. See the very recent question on ELL  [Why isn’t the pronoun “it” placed after But?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/153517/why-isn-t-the-pronoun-it-placed-after-but/153523#153523)