# Why isn’t the pronoun “it” placed after But?

Tags: conjunctions, ellipsis, parallelism

THE SOURCE: NY times

> Poland sent soldiers to fight alongside Americans in Iraq, **but is nonetheless** one of the few countries still hosting North Korean workers over Washington's objections.

Why doesn’t  the preposition “it” get placed before "is"? To make it go like this:

> But it is nonetheless...

Is it a kind of ellipsis?

Comment: Also a country is "She", not "it".

Comment: @stuartstevenson this is increasingly not the case (and frankly sounds weird already) https://english.stackexchange.com/a/204219/31679 and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12632/is-it-a-good-practice-to-refer-to-countries-ships-etc-using-the-feminine-form

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The two verb phrases *sent soldiers...* and *is nonetheless...* are **conjoined** by *but* and share the subject, *Poland*; parse it like this:

```
         sent soldiers ...
 Poland  but
         is nonetheless ...
```

Compare:

```
         went to bed 
   John  but
         could not sleep.
```

Comment: Couldn’t we use the pronoun to make two independent clause? John went to bed, but he couldn’t sleep

Comment: @StevanSlewa: They could. They didn't.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry, I didn’t understand what tried to imply?

Comment: They could use the pronoun but they didn't use it (for whatever reason).

Comment: @StevanSlewa: That is, yes, they *could* use the pronoun, but they aren't *required* to. Leaving it out is also allowed.

Comment: Arguably, the comma should not have been used since `but` is joining two halves of a compound predicate, rather than introducing another clause in a compound sentence.

Comment: @StevanSlewa I'm wondering if the use of "but" is throwing you here. Most typically you'll see this construction with "and" as the conjunction: "The dog ran across the yard, jumped over the fence, and sprinted down the alley." ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar))). -- This omission of the subject doesn't just work with "and". It works with other conjunctions like "but", too.

Answer (score 8):

It probably makes more sense to treat this as a kind of [parallelling](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/623/1/), rather than [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

The two sentences are

> **Poland** sent soldiers to fight alongside Americans in Iraq
>   **Poland** is nonetheless one of the few countries still hosting North Korean workers over Washington's objections.

Ellipsis and parallelling shorten a sentence by removing duplicated word sequences: in this case, the word **Poland**. An alternative way of shortening the sentence is to replace the second occurrence of **Poland** by **it**. The use of a pronoun is an alternative method of shortening the sentence, not a precursor to applying ellipsis or parallelling. The omitted word when the sentences are parallelled is therefore **Poland**, not **it**.

Comment: Why is that? It here gives the meaning of poland. So he wrote poland then would use “it” to refer to. How could it be paralleled?

Comment: Ellipsis and paralleling shorten a sentence by omitting word sequences that match **exactly**: Poland/Poland, not Poland/it.. Using a pronoun instead of a noun is an alternative way of shortening a sentence, rather than an initial step towad ellipsis or parallelling.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's a kind of ellipsis for style.  It doesn't change the meaning.

Other examples:

> She was top of her high school class, but (she) isn't planning to go to college.
>
> The computer can do many trillions of calculations per second, but (it) can't dream.